# Statistical estimate of original data that has been merged together

Tags: mathematical-statistics, methodology

I'm currently working with predicting monthly sales of maintenance for a certain type of machine. Say the machine types available are A, B and C, and I'm only interested in predicting maintenance sales for machine type A.

Now, the problem is that in my dataset, we can only see maintenance sales on a customer level, and also which machines customers own. I.e. at any maintenance occasion, we cannot see which machine type was served. Only that "customer 1" owns machines A and B and that they spent $1200 on maintenance some month.

Of course, it's impossible to know how much (if any) of the $1200 was used for machine A, and how much for B. But having a large set of this kind of data, are there any statistical methods for dealing with data that has been "merged" in this way?

Comment: Do you know *how many* of each type of machine each customer owns?

Comment: Yes, that is also known